# Discovering metadata about a PDF

Tags: pdf, file-metadata

Suppose I have a PDF and I want to obtain whatever metadata is available for that PDF. What utility should I use?

I find the piece of information I am usually most interested in knowing is the [paper size](http://www.prepressure.com/library/paper-size), something that PDF viewers usually don't report. E.g. is the PDF size letter, legal, A4 or something else? But the other information available may be of interest too.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

One of the canonical tools for this is `pdfinfo`, which comes with xpdf, if I recall. Example output:

```
[0 1017 17:10:17] ~/temp % pdfinfo test.pdf
Creator:        TeX
Producer:       pdfTeX-1.40.14
CreationDate:   Sun May 18 09:53:06 2014
ModDate:        Sun May 18 09:53:06 2014
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4)
Page rot:       0
File size:      19700 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

Comment: In Debian at least this is part of poppler-utils. I have a file here which pdfinfo reports as 595.2 x 841.44 pts. But this is not reported as A4. What decides to mark it as A4?

Comment: The names [are hardcoded](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/tree/utils/pdfinfo.cc?id=bd99616b9c06f96beadb68e015d2904b7fe2df1d): letter is 612 ± 0.1 x 792 ± 0.1, the magic sizes for DIN/ISO A are (all ±1 pt): 3370.98, 2383.64, 1685.49, 1191.82, 842.74, 595.91, ..., so it seems your page is a tiny bit too narrow for `pdfinfo` to pick that up.

Comment: I see, the bit of code `if ((fabs(w - 612) < 0.1 && fabs(h - 792) < 0.1) ||
 (fabs(w - 792) < 0.1 && fabs(h - 612) < 0.1))`?

Comment: That's letter, the A formats are in the loop with the `sqrt(2)`s.

Comment: This was (pre?)installed on both my Mac OS X and Ubuntu (unlike `exiftool`). So it gets my vote.

Answer (score 58):

Another utility worth looking into is [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/). It might not be the right tool in your specific case as it doesn't report any information on the geometry of the document but in general it is probably the most feature-complete tool for inspecting PDF metadata.

Here's an example of a command that will print all available meta information (`-a`), sorted by groups (`-G1`):

```
exiftool -a -G1 "$File"
```

The official documentation offers an overview of the supported PDF-related tags:

- [PDF Tags](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/PDF.html)
- [XMP PDF tags](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/XMP.html#pdf)
- [XMP dc tags](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/XMP.html#dc)

You can install exiftool on Debian/Ubuntu with:

```
sudo apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

---

If you are more into the GUI side of things you could give my project [PDFMtEd](https://github.com/Glutanimate/PDFMtEd) a try. It's a set of tools that serve as graphical frontends to exiftool and allow viewing and editing PDF metadata.

Here are a couple of screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is great! In particular I like that it shows all metadata. In my case I was looking for PDF/A metadata, which pdfinfo does not show.

Comment: This looks useful, but I'm confused why in Mac Finder's 'Get Info' panel it shows a lengthy URL for "Where from" (googleusercontent.com domain as it's a GDrive generated PDF) that does not appear in output of `exiftool -a -G1`. So the tool does not appear to report all metadata.